# Can a view function fail when returning big amounts of data

Tags: solidity

I have a question regarding `view` functions.

In my contract, I keep a map of structs, where the map `key` is a simple incrementing ID. I want to implement a viewer function which will essentially iterate through the map and collect its entries to a list, which is then returned to the caller.

Function prototype is something along the lines of this:

`function getArbitraryNumberOfStructs(uint256 n) external view returns(MyStruct[])`.

I was wondering, in case the mapping had, say, 1 million structs, and I decided to call the function with `n=1_000_000`, is there a scenario where the data read would fail?

Also it might be worth noting that I intend to call this function from a Web3 UI, not from another smart contract.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the return data from this function, you'll do an `eth_call` method. The gas limit for it would depend on the node on which the `call` is performed. When you do a call, the transaction still requires gas, just that it's not deducted from your account. And the node can decide upon the gas limit for `eth_call`. For example, Infura sets the gas limit at 2x the block gas limit ([source](https://community.infura.io/t/gas-limit-on-eth-call/1115/4)). So the answer is - it depends on the node.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I'm wondering, in case I take a different approach, and store my data in a big array, and just return this array from a function, would the gas be extremely low in that case and thus success would depend on the heap memory amount available?

Comment: Depends on the array size. But it's generally not a great idea to return a large array as it is. You can implement some sort of pagination (break into pages of let's say 100) and call each page separately. This will ensure that your functions don't break even if the array gets arbitrarily large. Or if you are sure the array won't get too big, you can return the whole array too.

Comment: Okay that was my idea, thank you so much for your input!