# how to estimate gas usage of a view function?

Tags: web3js, hardhat, brownie

according to this [question](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/119936/can-a-view-function-fail-when-returning-big-amounts-of-data) gas limit of `eth_call` depends on the node that you use, but still I wanted to have an estimate that how much gas that it use for my view function `eth_call` to be on safer side.

for example I wanted to know what is the maximum number of `n` that this function work with less than 30 million gas.

```
function ret(uint256 n) public view returns(uint256){
        uint256 a = 0;

        for(uint256 j = 0; j<n; j++){
            a = a + 1;
        }
        
        return a;
    }
```